# static pointer to itself!

Tags: c++

what's wrong with the following code:

```
class A
{
public:
 static A* p;

 A()
 {
  p = this;
 }
};
```

I got this link error:

error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static class A * A::p" (?p@A@@2PAV1@A)

I cannot figure out the point of this problem, please help..

Answer (score 14):

You need *storage* for that pointer. You *declared*, but did not *define* it. In the implementation (`.cpp`) file do:

```
A* A::p;
```

#### Edit 0:

By the way, do you really want to override that pointer every time a new instance of your class in created? Seems to me you are looking for the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#C.2B.2B).

#### Edit 1:

You *can* initialize static variables (and not unlike in Java, come to think of it, though the syntax is different). Say you have a static string member `foo` of a class `X`, then your implementation file might contain the following:

```
std::string X::foo = "Happy Leif Erikson Day!";
```

But be careful - constructors for static objects run before `main()` is entered and their order between translation units is undefined, which often leads to ["static initialization order fiasco"](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14).

Comment: It's static, it's zero by definition.

Comment: It works!! Is it because when I create an object, the static variable is not allocated? So I have to write codes to instantiate the static variable? Can I write a static field like in Java to initialize the static variables?

Comment: for sure he wants the singleton